# How do I add a css class to a tree node in Ext4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I would like to highlight some of the nodes in an Ext.tree.Panel.

In Ext3 I accomplished this by adding a class to the tree node ui object:

```
// add a class with to highlight the node
myTreeNode.getUI().addClass('highlightclass');

// remove the class to remove the highlighting
myTreeNode.getUI().removeClass('highlightclass');
```

What is the equivalent in Ext4?
I have been able to change the icon by setting the iconCls field of my node model, but I would really like to be able to set a class that allows me to highlight the whole node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer I found to my own question:

```
// add a css class to a specific tree node
myTreePanel.getView().addRowCls(myTreeNode,'highlightclass');

// remove a css class from a specific tree node
myTreePanel.getView().removeRowCls(myTreeNode,'highlightclass');
```

Comment: definately a better solution for your scenario.

Comment: I found the class disappeared every time the parent was expanded or collapsed

Comment: Same problem as @WendyLisaGibbons

Comment: Posted my own solution to the problem that worked better than what is described here.

Answer (score 2):

While the selected answer may work, in my version of ExtJS (4.0.7) as soon as I expand or collapse a node in my tree panel the css classes were all reset. I believe the more permanent way to fix this would be

```
myTreeNode.set('cls', 'highlightclass');
```

This will add your class to the specific tree node's td.x-grid-cell DOM element.

Hope that helps

Comment: I agree that this is the best solution for ExtJS 4.x, but for version 5 there's an issue too: hovering on the expander arrow, the class is overriden

Comment: Good know @qdev I haven't had the pleasure of dealing with ExtJS 5 yet.

Comment: here's a bug report that I've opened about this. It includes a fiddle as well: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?291787-cls-overriden-by-expander-arrow-hover-in-treePanel

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you will need to think of the tree instead as a treegrid.  Set up a columns definition for your tree with only one column, hide the header of the column and add a renderer to the column.

after that you can define your renderer like so with a css class defined for your highlighted rows and probably an attribute on the row model to tell which rows should be highlighted:

```
renderer: function(value, metaData){
    if (whatever you want here as a condition) {
        metaData.tdCls = "x-grid-row-alt-mine";
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: When I tried to implement this I lost all the tree indentations, but while investigating it I stumbled on the solution I ended up using. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My code is a little more complex, I can see why you lost the indentations with this snippet.